# Help with Flappy Bird Sketch

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c++, sketch

I am compiling the sketch found [here](https://github.com/huytd/arduino-flappybird). I just downloaded the .ino and .h files and opened them, so I have not modded the code at all. I keep getting the following error.

```
In file included from flappyDuino.ino:7:0:
Sprite.h:3: error: variable 'flappybird_frame_1' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'
 static unsigned char PROGMEM flappybird_frame_1[] = { 0x03, 0xF0, 0x0C, 0x48, 0x10, 0x84, 0x78, 0x8A, 0x84, 0x8A, 0x82, 0x42, 0x82, 0x3E, 0x44, 0x41,0x38, 0xBE, 0x20, 0x41, 0x18, 0x3E, 0x07, 0xC0 };

                                                 ^
In file included from flappyDuino.ino:7:0:
Sprite.h:4: error: variable 'flappybird_frame_2' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'
 static unsigned char PROGMEM flappybird_frame_2[] = { 0x03, 0xF0, 0x0C, 0x48, 0x10, 0x84, 0x20, 0x8A, 0x40, 0x8A, 0x40, 0x42, 0x7C, 0x3E, 0x82, 0x41, 0x84, 0xBE, 0x88, 0x41, 0x78, 0x3E, 0x07, 0xC0 };

                                                 ^
Sprite.h:5: error: variable 'bar_bottom' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'
 static unsigned char PROGMEM bar_bottom[] = { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x42, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E };

                                         ^
Sprite.h:6: error: variable 'bar_top' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'
 static unsigned char PROGMEM bar_top[] = { 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x42, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF };

                                      ^
variable 'flappybird_frame_1' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: What it says... make those variables `const`.

Comment: This is embarrassing. . . But how?

Comment: By adding the word `const` after the word `static`.

Comment: Thank you. I had const on the back of my head but wasn't sure where to put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrays need to be tagged with the keyword `const`.  It is possible that the original sketch was written using an earlier version of the IDE that you are using (or a later version?) and your version requires the `const` keyword whereas the author's doesn't.

Basically any arrays that are `PROGMEM` need the word `const` adding to them.  For instance, lines that start:

```
static unsigned char PROGMEM ...
```

need changing to:

```
static const unsigned char PROGMEM ...
```

Comment: Thank you for answering why the sketch would not contain the necessary const. BTW Does the ! symbol mean not throughout the Arduino IDE, so that the statement "if (!player.isDead()) means if isDead is not true then. . .

Comment: Yes, `!` is logical negation - true becomes false, false becomes true.  So !player.isDead() would logically be the same as (if the function existed) player.isAlive().